# Call onactivityresult method from arrayadapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

I am implementing a payment gateway. I have an array adapter and in this array adapter I have on activity result method how I call this method

Here is my code

//this is code inside my arrayadapter

```
public void onBuyPressed(View pressed) {
    /*
     * PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE will cause the payment to complete immediately.
     * Change PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE to - PAYMENT_INTENT_AUTHORIZE to only
     * authorize payment and capture funds later. - PAYMENT_INTENT_ORDER to
     * create a payment for authorization and capture later via calls from
     * your server.
     * 
     * Also, to include additional payment details and an item list, see
     * getStuffToBuy() below.
     */
    PayPalPayment thingToBuy = getThingToBuy(PayPalPayment.PAYMENT_INTENT_SALE);

    /*
     * See getStuffToBuy(..) for examples of some available payment options.
     */

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, PaymentActivity.class);

    // send the same configuration for restart resiliency
    intent.putExtra(PayPalService.EXTRA_PAYPAL_CONFIGURATION, config);

    intent.putExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_PAYMENT, thingToBuy);

    ((Activity) context).startActivityForResult(intent, 1);

}
```

//this is my OnactivityResultMethod

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("OnActivityCalled");

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PaymentConfirmation confirm = data
                    .getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirm != null) {
                try {
                    System.out
                            .println("Print 1 ............................"
                                    + confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                    System.out
                            .println("print 2 ........................... "
                                    + confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject()
                                            .toString(4));

                    Toast.makeText(
                            BuySpaceActivity.this,
                            "PaymentConfirmation info received from PayPal",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out
                            .println("an extremely unlikely failure occurred: "
                                    + e);
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            System.out.println("The user canceled.");
        } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
            System.out
                    .println("An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the error log

```
12-09 13:40:26.853: E/AndroidRuntime(25986): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-09 13:40:26.853: E/AndroidRuntime(25986): Process: com.dt.whosatthedoor, PID: 25986
12-09 13:40:26.853: E/AndroidRuntime(25986): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
12-09 13:40:26.853: E/AndroidRuntime(25986):    at com.dt.service.CustomBuySpaceAdapter.onBuyPressed(CustomBuySpaceAdapter.java:130)
12-09 13:40:26.853: E/AndroidRuntime(25986):    at com.dt.service.CustomBuySpaceAdapter$1.onClick(CustomBuySpaceAdapter.java:99)
12-09 13:40:26.853: E/AndroidRuntime(25986):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4757)
12-09 13:40:26.853: E/AndroidRuntime(25986):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19757)
12-09 13:40:26.853: E/AndroidRuntime(25986):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
12-09 13:40:26.853: E/AndroidRuntime(25986):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
12-09 13:40:26.853: E/AndroidRuntime(25986):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
12-09 13:40:26.853: E/AndroidRuntime(25986):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5233)
12-09 13:40:26.853: E/AndroidRuntime(25986):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
12-09 13:40:26.853: E/AndroidRuntime(25986):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
12-09 13:40:26.853: E/AndroidRuntime(25986):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
12-09 13:40:26.853: E/AndroidRuntime(25986):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: my question is i am not able to call onactivityresult method it throws exception

Comment: here is exception
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.dt.whosatthedoor
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast to android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity
com.dt.service.CustomBuySpaceAdapter.onBuyPressedcom.dt.service.CustomBuySpaceAdapter$1.onClick
android.view.View.performClick
android.view.View$PerformClick.runandroid.os.Handler.handleCallbackandroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage

Comment: Post the stack trace

Comment: check i edit my question

Comment: @user2894408 basically, in the constructor of adapter, what you passed for context?

Comment: i passed the context of the activity

Answer (score 3, accepted):

hey this method is only associated with the activity so this method has to be in the activity so take your onActivityResult method and put it on activity and you also check the context you passed in the arrayadapter

you should do like this

```
BuySpaceActivity act = (BuySpaceActivity) context;
    act.startCommentActivity(intent);
```

//make this method in your activity

```
public void startCommentActivity(Intent i) {
    startActivityForResult(i, 1);
}
```

//your onACtivityResult Method

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    System.out.println("OnActivityCalled");

    if (requestCode == 1) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            PaymentConfirmation confirm = data
                    .getParcelableExtra(PaymentActivity.EXTRA_RESULT_CONFIRMATION);
            if (confirm != null) {
                try {
                    System.out
                            .println("Print 1 ............................"
                                    + confirm.toJSONObject().toString(4));
                    System.out
                            .println("print 2 ........................... "
                                    + confirm.getPayment().toJSONObject()
                                            .toString(4));

                    Toast.makeText(
                            BuySpaceActivity.this,
                            "PaymentConfirmation info received from PayPal",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    System.out
                            .println("an extremely unlikely failure occurred: "
                                    + e);
                }
            }
        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            System.out.println("The user canceled.");
        } else if (resultCode == PaymentActivity.RESULT_EXTRAS_INVALID) {
            System.out
                    .println("An invalid Payment or PayPalConfiguration was submitted. Please see the docs.");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` in adapter class. It is meant to be used in `Activity` only. Write the method in the `Activity` which uses the adapter class.

Comment: your mean i have to code onActivityResult Method in activity then how i do call it from adapter

Comment: What action are you doing in list view item?

Comment: i am using on click listener on imageview and using view holder